# Handler postDelayed() stops working after long time

Tags: android, handler

In my android application, i am running a remote service which is started in the foreground

```
startForeground(1, notification)
```

so that it is not killed. In this service a task is allowed to run every 15 minutes like this and repeated.

```
handler.post(scheduledTask);
    class ScheduledTask implements Runnable{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Do the task
            // Repeat the task after the interval
            handler.postDelayed(this,INTERVAL);
        }
    }
```

I kept this application on for a day. But after midnight, it stopped working for a like around 5-6 hours and then early mornign when i resumed the application, it continued.

Could someone tell me what could have caused this issue ? I tested this in a Galaxy Note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) better than a postDelayed. I can't post code right now, but I had the same needs and AlarmManager proved to be much better than postDelayed.

You'll need some kind of alarm receiver (BroadcastReceiver, for example) that will start your Service every time the Alarm event (an Intent) occurs.

Comment: I would need an alarm manager if i wanted to start and stop the service, but here the service is always on. The service is stopped only if i stop it. I just need a task within the service to be repeated every fifteen minutes. It does the job but in long run, i noticed this.

Comment: I had logged the data. The service never died, it is just that the handler did not execute when the phone went to sleep i guess

Comment: Else is there a way to execute a block of code within the service with an AlarmManager() ?

Comment: I needed a service sending the user's location every 5 minutes and using AlarmManager was the best solution I found. I also logged the data when using postDelayed and the service simply stopped logging the location, so it looks similar to what you have right now. To execute a block of code I used an IntentService, which reacts to an intent and kills himself after doing the job.